# Get DB-Data from Server

Tags: android

I have a problem with my application. I need the data from my MySQL-Database on the server. Usally I'm using HTTP-Posts, but this time I'm have to get a lot of db-Entrys. So I thought, that i'm just copying the database to the device. But here is the next problem: The Database on the device has the same structure like the db on the server, and additional 2 extra tables, to save some local data. 
Finally my question is, how to get a lot of data from my database?

One extra question: is it possible/effective to use 2 local databases? So i could use 1 for local data and the other one for the server data. Then it would be possible to copy the db, but i need also an mysql-query, because i don't want to copy the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible to have 2 local db, and the best way to download an entire db from server is to dump the mysql db on server to a sqlite db, and so you may download the sqlite db from your mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Well choosing a database is depends on your project requirement. If your data is getting updated frequently on server and you want the display the updated data to the user. Do not copy database in mobile. Instead of it use webservices to get data from remote server.

And Yea, you can create two database in Android, nothing wrong in it. But again I would suggest that for only two tables do not create separate database.That can be merged in single database.

**Summary**

*Frequently Updates in Data :* Use MySql + Webservice

*Static Data :* Go for local db